# Configure SnakeYAML to escape strings with double quotes instead of single quotes [java]

Tags: java, snakeyaml

I want SnakeYAML to, by default, output strings that contain special characters (such as a colon) that are wrapped in **double quotes** instead of single quotes. I've been pulling my hair out for hours on how to accomplish this with the SnakeYAML API, but I have found no leads. Example:

Say I have a **value**: "Yes: No". I want SnakeYAML to output this value like this:

```
key: "Yes: No"
```

with double quotes instead of single quotes. I have tried using multiple default scalar options with the `DumperOptions` class to no avail. I have to store all the values in my YAML file without any quotes (for reasons), except of course for values that contain special characters.

Here is the code I'm using to write to a YAML file for context:

````
public void writeMeta(String key, String value) {
        
        try {
            
            Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
            FileReader reader = new FileReader(this.metaYAML);
            Map<String, String> meta = yaml.load(reader);
            
            
            if (meta == null) {
                meta = new HashMap<>();
            }
            if (value.equals("")) {
                value = null;
            }
            meta.put(key, value);
            

            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(this.metaYAML);
            
            DumperOptions options = new DumperOptions();
            options.setDefaultFlowStyle(DumperOptions.FlowStyle.BLOCK);
            options.setDefaultScalarStyle(DumperOptions.ScalarStyle.PLAIN);
            
            new Yaml(options).dump(meta, writer);

            writer.close();
            reader.close();
            
            
        } catch (IOException e) {
            new ErrorDialog(new IOException("Could not parse/write to the meta.yaml file.", e));
        }
        
    }
    ```
````